# How can I filter through api data and print name to console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm frustrated right now. I am trying to filter data in an API and trying to push them to a useState hook array and print them to the console. I am using React and really struggling. Below is the code.

#### TimeChart.js

```
const TimeChart = () =>{
    const [tournament, setTournament] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get("https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/lol/scores/json/Competitions?key=94c287b249d74701adf60e03aa398884")
        .then((res) =>{
            let data = res.data;

        let lcsT = data.map((item) => item.Name === "NA LCS").Name;
        let lecT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LEC").Name;
        let lplT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LPL").Name;
        let lckT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LCK").Name;
        let msiT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "Mid-Season Invitational").Name;
        let worldsT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "World Championship").Name;

        setTournament([lcsT, lecT, lplT, lckT, msiT, worldsT]);
           console.log(tournament);
        })
    },[])
```

If you haven't figured it out yet I'm trying to get names of tournaments and filter throught their names only and push them to the `setTournament` useState hook array and print them to the console but I get an `undefined` returned in the console.

#### Something I also tried:

```
let lcsT = data.map((item) => item.Name === "NA LCS");
        let lcs = lcsT.map((item) => item.Name);

        let lecT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LEC");
        let lec = lecT.map((item) => item.Name);

        let lplT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LPL");
        let lpl = lplT.map((item) => item.Name);

        let lckT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LCK");
        let lck = lckT.map((item) => item.Name);

        let msiT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "Mid-Season Invitational");
        let msi = msiT.map((item) => item.Name);

        let worldsT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "World Championship");
        let worlds = worldsT.map((item) => item.Name);
        setTournament(lcs, lec, lpl, lck, msi, worlds);
    console.log(tournament);
```

But this returns an empty array in the console.

#### Something I tried as well:

```
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                if( data[i].Name === "NA LCS"){
                    let lcs = data[i].Name;
                    setTournament(lcs);
                } else if(data[i].Name === "LEC"){
                    let lec = data[i].Name;
                    setTournament(lec);
                } else if(data[i].Name === "LPL"){
                     let lpl = data[i].Name;
                     setTournament(lpl);
                } else if(data[i].Name === "LCK"){
                     let lck = data[i].Name;
                     setTournament(lck);  
                 } else if (data[i].Name === "Mid-Season Invitational"){
                     let msi = data[i].Name;
                     setTournament(msi);    
                 } else if (data[i].Name === "World Championship"){
                     let worlds = data[i].Name;
                     setTournament(worlds);
                 }
                 console.log(tournament);
            }
```

If anyone can point out to me what I am doing wrong, please do so, it's driving me crazy!

Thanks!

Comment: You can't immediately log a state change. You'll need to use [a `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to check for changes in state. `useEffect(() => console.log(tournament), [tournament]);`

Comment: Alright, I tried that and it still returns ```undefined``` . Thanks though :D

Comment: 1) `let lcsT = data.map((item) => item.Name === "NA LCS").Name;` 2) `let lecT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LEC").Name;` --> there are multiple issues at play here. In 1, `.map()` whose call back will return the result of `item.Name === "NA LCS"`. This will be an array of `truthy`, `falsy` values. None of these will have a prop `.Name`. In 2. `.filter()` returns an `"Array"`. This array will have objects and **"may be"** one or more of those filtered object/s may have the prop `.Name`.

Comment: Please try: `setTournament(data.filter(({ Name }) => ["NA LCS", "LEC", "LPL", "LCK", "Mid-Season Invitational", "World Championship"].includes(Name)).map(({ Name }) => Name));`. If you try, do share feedback.

Comment: @jsN00b Thank you this does indeed work! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong in using React state hook.

You can't use state variable as soon as you call `setState`.

e.g. You used `setTournament(xxxx); console.log(tournament);` in your code.
This is mistake.

e.g. You made a mistake to set an array in `tournament` state: `setTournament(lcs, lec, lpl, lck, msi, worlds);`.

**You cannot set an array by passing multiple parameters.**

**`setState` function can only accept a parameter.**

You should change it by the following:

```
newTournament = [lcs, lec, lpl, lck, msi, worlds];
console.log(newTournament);
setTournament(newTournament);
```

According to your comments, you can use the following code.

```
const dataMap = {};
data.forEach(item => {
  if (
    item.Name === "NA LCS" ||
    item.Name === "LEC" ||
    item.Name === "LPL" ||
    item.Name === "LCK" ||
    item.Name === "Mid-Season Invitational" ||
    item.Name === "World Championship"
  ) {
    dataMap[item.name] = true;
  }
});
const newTournament = Object.keys(dataMap);
console.log(newTournament);
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I did that but this is what is returned to the console:

```
(6) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

```

Comment: @Wiaan.Duvenhage Please fix your code `let lcsT = data.map((item) => item.Name === "NA LCS").Name;`. `map` function returns an array. So you can't use `.Name` in array.

Comment: Alright I did that, which is putting an array inside of an array now, but I only want the name not the entire array. Here is what is returned to the console:

(6) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)].

What I actually want is:

(6) ['NA LCS', 'LEC', 'LPL', 'LCK', 'Mid-Seaons Invitational', 'World Championship']

Comment: @Wiaan.Duvenhage Could you print data in console to show me? your code doesn't make sense.  `let lecT = data.filter((item) => item.Name === "LEC");
let lec = lecT.map((item) => item.Name);`  `lec` variable will hold ['LEC', 'LEC', ...]

Comment: Do you have discord perhaps? I can explain better on there?

Comment: @Wiaan.Duvenhage I updated my answer. Please use the code in it. And let me know.

Comment: @Wiaan.Duvenhage if this is correct, please update your post as well. You need to describe what you really wanted to get from your API result as well as the current code snippets.

Comment: That fixed it thank you very much!!!! I will update my post